# Reading a CSV file in C and dealing with commas in the data

Tags: c, csv, file-handling

I have written a code to read a csv file in c. The file contains data of games and i am supposed to read it and sort it according to the score and print the top 10 rated games. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define tablesize 18626

typedef struct
{
    char title[200];
    char platform[20];
    char Score[20];
    char release_year[20];
} dict;

void printValues(dict *values)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        printf("title->%s,platform->%s,Score->%s,release->%s\n", values[i].title, values[i].platform, values[i].Score, values[i].release_year);
    }
}

void sort(dict *values)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tablesize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < tablesize; j++)
        {
            int a = *values[i].Score - '0';
            int b = *values[j].Score - '0';
            // printf("%d %d\n",values[i].Score,values[j].Score);
            if (a < b)
            {
                dict temp = values[i];
                values[i] = values[j];
                values[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("t4_ign.csv", "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return 0;
    }
    char buff[1024];
    int row = 0, column = 0;
    int count = 0;
    dict *values = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(buff, 1024, fp))
    {
        column = 0;
        row++;
        count++;
        values = realloc(values, sizeof(dict) * count);
        if (NULL == values)
        {
            perror("realloc");
            break;
        }
        if (row == 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        char *field = strtok(buff, ",");
        while (field)
        {
            if (column == 0)
            {
                strcpy(values[i].title, field);
            }
            if (column == 1)
            {
                strcpy(values[i].platform, field);
            }
            if (column == 2)
            {
                strcpy(values[i].Score, field);
            }
            if (column == 3)
            {
                strcpy(values[i].release_year, field);
            }
            field = strtok(NULL, ",");
            column++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("File loaded!\n", fp);
    sort(values);
    printValues(values);
    free(values);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem i am facing is that the CSV file's Title field has commas in it and it thus differentiates the data separated by the commas as different columns which gives an error in loading the data in the struct.

Here are two example lines of the input file. Quotes are used when the title contains commas.

```
"The Chronicles of Narnia: The Lion, The Witch and The Wardrobe",PlayStation 2,8,2005  
The Chronicles of Narnia: Prince Caspian,Wireless,5,2008
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the title field enclosed in `"` or some other symbols?  If not, how do you distinguish between a title like `Big,House` and two comma separated values `Big,House`?

Comment: If the title is the *only* field that might contain commas, you'll have to work from the other end (say with `strrchr(buff, ',')`) and then what's left is the title. If you can use a `TAB` separated file it would be rather easier.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes  the titles that contain commas are enclosed in quotes

Comment: @user3121023
"The Chronicles of Narnia: The Lion, The Witch and The Wardrobe",PlayStation 2,8,2005
The Chronicles of Narnia: Prince Caspian,Wireless,5,2008

Comment: Well, there's the beginning of the answer to your problem, you have to read the title from the leading `"` to the trailing `"`, you can't read from the first character to the first comma.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes the title is the only field but I'm looking for an overall solution incase i encounter this again in the future

Comment: Please post the example lines *in the question*. In the first one, the title is contained in `"quotes"`, so you should extract the first field with the appropriate delimiter. It does not have to be same for each call to `strtok`. But the second example does not have those quote marks. Post the *exact* lines copy/pasted into the question (and formatted as code).

Comment: @WeatherVane My dear sir, those are exact examples copied and pasted. As stated earlier the titles containing commas are enclosed in quotes while the titles not containing commas are not

Comment: @Sukhman, the problem is not that the examples are not accurate, the problem is that they are in comments rather than in the question.

Comment: Nonetheless, please post them in the question itself.

Comment: "Any suggestions?"   I strongly suggest you reformat the code with readable indentation.

Comment: The correct(TM) solution is to implement a serious CSV parser in a state machine. You might want to research for existing libraries, use one of them directly or just use their source as a base for your code.

Comment: Note that `strtok` is not very suitable to parse CSV, because it will skip empty fields.

Comment: All important information should be inside the question itself. It should not be necessary for someone wanting to answer the question to read all the comments beforehand. The fact that the title is in quotes is extremely important information that **must** be inside the question, because it changes the nature of the question significantly. An example of the input should be provided inside the question (not as a comment). I have therefore edited the question for you.

Comment: Please note that your question would be of higher quality if you provided a [mre] of the problem. The code you have posted is not minimal, because the problem you are asking about is how to parse a line of input, but your posted code also does other things not related to this problem, such as sorting.

Comment: The easy solution is to switch from `csv` to `tsv`; none of this fiddling with quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Since quotes are used for the title field when it contains commas, I suggest you check to see if the `"` has been used. If so, use that delimiter for the first item.

```
char *field;
if(buff[0] == '"') {
    field = strtok(buff, "\"");
}
else {
    field = strtok(buff, ",");
}
```

The first one will leave a comma as the first character of the next field, but the next `strtok` will filter that off, since it does not allow "empty" fields.

Comment: In your question, you wrote: `"The first one will leave a comma as the first character of the next field, but the next strtok will filter that off, since it does not allow "empty" fields.`" This statement is correct if the fields are indeed empty. However, a single whitespace character is sufficient for `strtok` to consider the space between a `"` and a `,` to be an additional field. Therefore, this solution does not appear ideal, but it is still a nice and simple solution, so I am upvoting it.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yes, but the examples do no show any redundant whitespace. Because both the title and platform might contain them, it would be better to trim leading and trailing whitespace from the tokenised strings. For the date and score fields, the delimiter string can be `" ,\t\r\n"` which will also trim the trailing newline retained by `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `strtok` does not suit your needs, because it considers the quotation marks as characters like any other. Therefore, when `strtok` sees a comma, it won't care whether the comma is inside quotation marks or not.

Also, as someone else pointed out in the comments section, another problem with `strtok` is that it skips empty fields.

Therefore, I do not recommend using `strtok` for what you want to do.

In order to solve your problem, I recommend that you write your own function that does something very similar to `strtok` and [`strsep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html), but if the first non-[whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) character is a quotation mark, it considers the next quotation mark as the delimiter instead of the next comma. In the code below, I named this function `my_strsep`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NUM_LINES 2

//this function is equivalent to the POSIX function "strsep", except
//that it always uses "," as a delimiter, unless the first
//non-whitespace character is a quotation mark, in which case it //skips the quotation mark and uses the next quotation mark as a
//delimiter, also consuming the next comma
char *my_strsep( char **restrict stringp )
{
    char *p = *stringp;
    char *start;
    char delimiter = ',';

    //do nothing if *stringp is 
    if ( *stringp == NULL )
        return NULL;

    //skip all whitespace characters
    while ( isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
        p++;

    //remember start of field
    start = p;

    //determine whether this field uses quotation marks
    if ( *p == '"' )
    {
        //set delimiter to quotation mark instead of comma
        delimiter = '\"';

        //skip the first quotation mark
        p++;
    }

    //remember the start of the string
    start = p;

    while ( *p != delimiter )
    {
        if ( *p == '\0' )
        {
            if ( delimiter == '\"' )
            {
                fprintf( stderr,
                    "Warning: Encountered end of string before the "
                    "second quotation mark!\n"
                );
            }

            //pass information back to calling function
            *stringp = NULL;
            return start;
        }

        p++;
    }

    //overwrite the delimiter with a null character
    *p = '\0';

    //go past the delimiter
    p++;

    //skip the comma too, if quotation marks are being used
    if ( delimiter == '\"' )
    {
        //skip all whitespace characters
        while ( isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
            p++;

        //skip the comma
        if ( *p == ',' )
            p++;
    }

    //pass information back to calling function
    *stringp = p;
    return start;
}

int main( void )
{
    char lines[NUM_LINES][200] = {
        "\"The Chronicles of Narnia: The Lion, The Witch and The Wardrobe\",PlayStation 2,8,2005",
        "The Chronicles of Narnia: Prince Caspian,Wireless,5,2008"
    };

    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_LINES; i++ )
    {
        char *p, *q;

        printf( "Processing line #%d:\n", i + 1 );

        p = lines[i];

        while ( ( q = my_strsep( &p ) ) != NULL )
        {
            printf( "Found field: %s\n", q );
        }

        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Processing line #1:
Found field: The Chronicles of Narnia: The Lion, The Witch and The Wardrobe
Found field: PlayStation 2
Found field: 8
Found field: 2005

Processing line #2:
Found field: The Chronicles of Narnia: Prince Caspian
Found field: Wireless
Found field: 5
Found field: 2008
```

As you can see, the function `my_strsep` can handle fields both with and without quotation marks.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_TOPPINGS = 2;
const int MAX_DONUTS = 50;

struct donutType {
    string name;
    bool type;
    double price;
    string filling;
    string toppings[MAX_TOPPINGS];
};

ifstream getFileStream(string);
int getDonuts(ifstream&, donutType[]);
bool continueMenu(string);
void sortByPrice(donutType[], int);
int searchByName(const donutType[], int, string);
void removeDonutFromList(donutType[], int&, int);
int getCheapestDonut(const donutType[], int);
void soldDonut(donutType, donutType[], int&);
void outputSoldDonuts(ofstream&, const donutType[], int);
void displayAvailableDonuts(const donutType[], int);
string allCaps(string);

/**
 * The main function to manage the donut ordering program.
 *
 * @return The exit status of the program.
 */
int main() {
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile("sold.csv");
    string filename;
    string request;
    donutType donuts[MAX_DONUTS];
    donutType soldDonuts[MAX_DONUTS];
    int amtDonuts = 0;
    int amtSold = 0;
    double total = 0;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    // gets step 1 the input stream
    infile = getFileStream("Enter a donut file: ");

    // step 2 get total donuts
    amtDonuts = getDonuts(infile, donuts);

    // step 3 print to console
    cout << "Welcome to Hank's Donut World!\n\n";
    while (true) {

        // step 4 print the available donuts to console
        displayAvailableDonuts(donuts, amtDonuts);

        //step 5 ask for user input
        string nameEnteredByUser;
        cout << "Enter donut name or cheapest: ";
        getline(cin, nameEnteredByUser);

        // step 6 check the user input choice and call function accordingly
        int donutIndex;
        transform(nameEnteredByUser.begin(), nameEnteredByUser.end(),
                nameEnteredByUser.begin(), ::tolower);

        if (nameEnteredByUser.compare("cheapest") == 0)
            donutIndex = getCheapestDonut(donuts, amtDonuts);
        else
            donutIndex = searchByName(donuts, amtDonuts, nameEnteredByUser);

        // step 7 check if the search results was empty
        if (donutIndex == -1) {
            cout << "Donut not found!\n";
            continue;
        }

        // step 8 print the selection to console
        cout << "You selected " << donuts[donutIndex].name
                << ".\nExcellent choice!\n";

        // Step 9 inserting the sold donut into solddonuts array
        total += donuts[donutIndex].price;
        soldDonuts[amtSold] = donuts[donutIndex];
        amtSold++;

        // Step 10 removing the donut from donuts array
        removeDonutFromList(donuts, amtDonuts, donutIndex);

        // Step 11 choice to continue with more purchase
        bool complete = continueMenu("Will this complete your order? ");
        if (!complete) {
            if (amtDonuts > 0)
                continue; // go to Step 4
            else
                break; // End the program if there are no available donuts left

        }

        // Step 13 sort the donuts sold by price using bubble sort
        sortByPrice(soldDonuts, amtSold);

        // Step 14
        if (outfile.is_open()) {
            outfile << "Sold," << fixed << setprecision(2) << total << "\n";
            outputSoldDonuts(outfile, soldDonuts, amtSold);
        } else {
            cerr << "Error opening output file.\n";
        }
        break; // End the program
    }

    return 0;
}

/**
 * Retrieves an input file stream for a given filename after prompting the user.
 *
 * @param msg The message to prompt the user for the filename.
 * @return An ifstream object for the specified filename.
 */
ifstream getFileStream(string msg) {
    ifstream fileStream;
    string fileName;

    while (true) {
        // Prompt user for a filename
        cout << msg;
        getline(cin, fileName);

        // Open the file stream
        fileStream.open(fileName);

        // Check if the file stream is open
        if (fileStream.is_open()) {
            break;
        } else {
            fileStream.clear(); // Clear any error flags
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Clear input buffer
        }
    }

    return fileStream;
}

/**
 * Reads donut data from an input file stream into a struct array of donutType.
 *
 * @param infile An input file stream containing donut data.
 * @param donuts An array of donutType to store the read data.
 * @return The number of donuts read from the file.
 */
int getDonuts(ifstream &infile, donutType donuts[]) {
    const int MAX_RECORDS = 50;
    size_t MAX_CHARS = 100;
    char line[MAX_CHARS];
    int count = 0;

    // Read and ignore the header line
    infile.getline(line, MAX_CHARS);

    // Read the CSV file line by line
    while (!infile.fail() && count < MAX_RECORDS) {
        // Read the entire line into 'line'
        infile.getline(line, MAX_CHARS);

        // Create a strings to parse the line
        string lineString(line);
        if(lineString.size() < 2)
            break;
        // Tokenize the line based on commas
        size_t start = 0;
        size_t end = lineString.find(',');

        // Read name
        donuts[count].name = lineString.substr(0, end);
        //add plus one to skip the comma
        lineString = lineString.substr(end+1);

        // Read type
        end = lineString.find(',');
        donuts[count].type = (lineString.substr(0, end) == "Cake");
        lineString = lineString.substr(end+1);

        // Read filling
        end = lineString.find(',');
        donuts[count].filling = lineString.substr(0, end);
        lineString = lineString.substr(end+1);

        // Read toppings
        end = lineString.find(',');
        donuts[count].toppings[0] = lineString.substr(0, end);
        lineString = lineString.substr(end+1);

        end = lineString.find(',') ;
        donuts[count].toppings[1] = lineString.substr(0, end);
        lineString = lineString.substr(end+1);

        // Read price
        donuts[count].price = stod(lineString);

        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

/**
 * Displays a prompt and waits for user input to continue or exit.
 *
 * @param prompt The message to display as a prompt.
 * @return True if the user chooses to continue, false if the user chooses to exit.
 */
bool continueMenu(string prompt) {
    string input;

    while (true) {
        cout << prompt;
        getline(cin, input);

        // Convert the input to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison
        transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), ::tolower);

        if (input == "no")
            return false;
        else if (input == "yes")
            return true;
        else
            cerr << "Invalid input. Please enter 'Yes' or 'No' (case insensitive).\n";

    }
}

/**
 * Sorts an array of donuts based on their prices in ascending order using bubble sort.
 *
 * @param donuts An array of donuts to be sorted.
 * @param amtDonuts The number of donuts in the array.
 */
void sortByPrice(donutType donuts[], int amtDonuts) {
    for (int i = 0; i < amtDonuts - 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < amtDonuts - i - 1; ++j) {
            // Compare prices and swap if needed
            if (donuts[j].price > donuts[j + 1].price) {
                // Swap
                donutType temp = donuts[j];
                donuts[j] = donuts[j + 1];
                donuts[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Searches for a donut by name in an array of donuts.
 *
 * @param donuts An array of donuts to be searched.
 * @param amtDonuts The number of donuts in the array.
 * @param name The name of the donut to be searched.
 * @return The index of the found donut if present, otherwise -1.
 */
int searchByName(const donutType donuts[], int amtDonuts, string name) {

    transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), ::tolower);

    for (int i = 0; i < amtDonuts; ++i) {
        string donutName = donuts[i].name;
        transform(donutName.begin(), donutName.end(), donutName.begin(),
                ::tolower);
        if (donutName.compare(name) == 0)
            return i; // Return the index if the name is found
    }
    return -1; // Return -1 if the name is not found
}

/**
 * Finds the index of the cheapest donut in an array of donuts.
 *
 * @param donuts An array of donuts to be searched.
 * @param amtDonuts The number of donuts in the array.
 * @return The index of the cheapest donut if the array is not empty, otherwise -1.
 */
int getCheapestDonut(const donutType donuts[], int amtDonuts) {
    if (amtDonuts <= 0)
        return -1; // Return -1 if the array is empty

    // Initialize to maximum possible value
    double minPrice = donuts[0].price;
    // Index of the cheapest donut
    int minIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < amtDonuts; ++i) {
        if (donuts[i].price < minPrice) {
            minPrice = donuts[i].price;
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return minIndex;
}

/**
 * Converts a given string to uppercase.
 *
 * @param s The input string to be converted to uppercase.
 * @return The uppercase version of the input string.
 */
string allCaps(string s) {
    string upper = s;

    for (char &c : upper)
        c = toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));

    return upper;
}

/**
 * Removes a donut from the list based on the provided index.
 *
 * @param donuts The array of donuts.
 * @param amtDonuts The current number of donuts in the array.
 * @param removeIndex The index of the donut to be removed.
 */
void removeDonutFromList(donutType donuts[], int &amtDonuts, int removeIndex) {
    if (removeIndex < 0 || removeIndex >= amtDonuts) {
        cerr << "Invalid index to remove. Index out of range." << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Shift elements to fill the gap
    for (int i = removeIndex; i < amtDonuts - 1; ++i) {
        donuts[i] = donuts[i + 1];
    }

    // Decrement the amount of donuts
    amtDonuts--;
}

/**
 * Outputs information about sold donuts to an output file.
 *
 * @param outfile The output file stream.
 * @param soldDonuts The array of sold donuts.
 * @param amtSold The current number of sold donuts in the array.
 */
void outputSoldDonuts(ofstream &outfile, const donutType soldDonuts[],
        int amtSold) {

    if (!outfile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error: Output file is not open." << endl;
        return;
    }

    outfile << fixed << setprecision(2);
    outfile << "Name,Type,Filling,Topping1,Topping2,Price" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < amtSold; ++i) {
        outfile << soldDonuts[i].name << ",";
        outfile << (soldDonuts[i].type ? "Cake" : "Dough") << ",";
        outfile << soldDonuts[i].filling << ",";
        outfile << soldDonuts[i].toppings[0] << ",";
        outfile << soldDonuts[i].toppings[1] << ",";
        outfile << soldDonuts[i].price << "\n";
    }
}

/**
 * Displays the list of available donuts with their names and prices.
 *
 * @param donuts The array of available donuts.
 * @param amtDonuts The current number of available donuts in the array.
 */
void displayAvailableDonuts(const donutType donuts[], int amtDonuts) {
    cout << "List of donuts" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < amtDonuts; ++i)
        cout << donuts[i].name << " " << donuts[i].price << endl;

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: This code is C++, not the OP's desire for an answer in C. This code has no "special handling" for quoted fields in the CSV.